# Finding the area of the parallelogram spanned by vectors

Tags: vectors

Hello everyone we have exams tomorrow and i am practising vectors and i wanted some help here. Finding the area of the parallelogram spanned by vectors <-1,0,2> and <-2,-2,2> 
I have not tried anything since I have no idea. I consider this as revision I have looked at several examples but most are complex and so i want to be helped on this one.

Comment: Please help me solve this one just for revision.

Comment: Please help yourself by putting the title of your question into Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I could have done.Just a hint towards exams.

$$Area = {\vert\vec a \times \vec b\vert}$$

$${\vert\vec a \times \vec b\vert}$$= $$ \begin{vmatrix}
         i &  j &  k \\
        -1 & 0 & 2 \\
        -2 & -2 & 2 \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$
now that we got our tangent vector specified,
$$ \begin{vmatrix}
         0 & 2 \\
         -2 & 2 \\
        \end{vmatrix} i -\begin{vmatrix}
         -1 & 2 \\
         -2 & 2 \\
        \end{vmatrix} j + \begin{vmatrix}
         -1 & 0\\
         -2 & 2 \\
        \end{vmatrix} k$$
∴ your equation of line should be;
$$ 4i-(-2+4)j+2k = 4i+2j+2k$$

Thus Area = $${\vert\vec a \times \vec b\vert} = \sqrt{4^2 + 2^2 +2^2}=\sqrt{24}$$ 
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

The area of the parallelogram spanned by two vectors is the magnitude of the cross-product. The cross product is $<4,-2,2>$, having magnitude $\sqrt{24}$.