# Basic geometric question on areas spanned by vectors and the triangle inequality

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I came across this diagram in [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/140929496X):

[image]

I'm probably missing something obvious, but this seems to contradict the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), and I would imagine to be correct only when $\vec c =\vec 0.$

Comment: $b+c$ here is a vector, not necessarily the length of the particular segment

Comment: @Vasya Right... The area is the [magnitude of the cross-product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1334281/527495)... Does the plot seem correct just from looking at it, though?

Comment: The plot looks correct, just read it more closely, the sum of areas of two smaller parallelograms is equal to the area of the biggest parallelogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all the vectors $\underline{a}$, $\underline{b}$ and $\underline{c}$, and therefore also $\underline{b}+\underline{c}$ are **co-planar** then it is easy to see that you can add the areas of parallelograms $CEFD$ and $ACDB$, then subtract area $ACE$ and add area $DBF$ then you do indeed have area $AEFB$.

You may be misreading the diagram as a parallelipiped.

Comment: Nailed it! I was in 3D, where I didn't see it being true.